# Return JSON response instead of 401 Blade file

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5

I am using AuthBasic for API authentication in a Laravel project,
I have this problem: when the API request authentication is invalid instead of displaying the JSON response it returns the 401 default blade view template.

Here is the code:

**app\Http\Middleware\AuthBasic.php**

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{   
    if (Auth::onceBasic()) {
        return response()->json(["message", "Authentication Required!"], 401);
    } else {
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the Solution:

app\Exceptions\Handler.php

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{   
    if ($request->is('api/*') || $request->wantsJson())
    {
        $json = [
            'success' => false,
            'error' => [
                'code' => $exception->getCode(),
                'message' => $exception->getMessage(),
            ],
        ];
        return response()->json($json, 401);
    }
    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the 401 or change it to 200 from this line:

```
return response()->json(["message", "Authentication Required!"], 401);
```

See the reference, the second parameter is defining the http code to send the browser. [401] in you case.
https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Routing/ResponseFactory.html#method_json

Comment: I changed it and still i get the same ,

I think that when the API request has no or invalid authentication from somewhere else is redirecting to 401 blade view file.

Ex: when I try the opposite it gives me the json response :

if (!Auth::onceBasic()) {   
      return response()->json(["message", "Authentication Required!"], 401);
    }

Answer (score 0):

This will fix your problem, probably!

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{   
    $result = Auth::onceBasic();

    if($result === 401)
        return response()->json(["message", "Authentication Required!"]);
    else
        return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: No, bro :(
Thanks anyway for your help :)

Comment: Did the error changed or you still get the same error!?

Answer (score 0):

So here is a half Solution for this problem:

[vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard.php](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Auth/SessionGuard.html)

```
    public function onceBasic($field = 'email', $extraConditions = [])
{
    $credentials = $this->basicCredentials($this->getRequest(), $field);

    if (! $this->once(array_merge($credentials, $extraConditions))) {
        //return $this->failedBasicResponse();
        return response()->json(["Message" => "Authentication Required!"], 401);
    }
}
```

So Instead of returning the Failed Basic Response it will return the JSON Message, but I don't want to make changes in Laravel Core Files, because in case of update they will get lost !

So Any Idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Attached is a solution that doesn't require modifying any core files. Just use a try - catch block.

```
    try {
        $response = Auth::Basic();
       //or $response = Auth::onceBasic();
    }
    catch (\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\UnauthorizedHttpException $e) {
        return response()->json([
            'message'     => 'Authentication failed'
        ]);
    }

    return $next($request);
```

You can also use `\Exception $e` to catch any type of exception, instead of only UnauthorizedHttpException.